# Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

So when I run the command "mvn clean spring-boot:run" I get the following error:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I know this might seem like a duplicate question because there are similar questions on StackOverflow but they are not the same. I can't find any explanation to this line:

```
Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url
```

I'm new to springboot and it's the first time I'm playing with something like this.
I will leave my pom.xml file here.
Any help is very appreciated, 
Thank you for your time!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>pt.ulisboa.tecnico.socialsoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>quizzes-tutor-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Quizzes Tutor Backend</name>
    <description>Tutor System for the Software Architecture Course</description>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>fenix-ashes-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/nexus/content/groups/fenix-ashes-maven-repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Allows multiple properties files-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

<!--Git Hook-->
<!--            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.github.phillipuniverse</groupId>
                        <artifactId>githook-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <hooks>
                                        <pre-push>
                                            BRANCH=$(git rev-parse &#45;&#45;abbrev-ref HEAD)
                                            if [[ "$BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
                                                cd backend
                                                exec mvn clean -Ptest test
                                            fi
                                        </pre-push>
                                    </hooks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>-->

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn
                            more about this plugin, visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <useFile>false</useFile>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>/static/export/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency of spring-boot-starter-web but with more recent version without vulnerabilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Access Control -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- In memory database for tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Fenix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fenixedu</groupId>
            <artifactId>feaf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fenixedu</groupId>
            <artifactId>feaf4j-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import/Export -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spock testing framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Specific Groovy version rather than the one specified by spock-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my application.properties file:

```
## Profile specific properties
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@

## maven directory
maven.basedir=@project.basedir@

## Datasource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# A list of all Hikari parameters with a good explanation is available on https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby
# This property controls the minimum number of idle connections that HikariCP tries to maintain in the pool. Default: same as maximumPoolSize
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=10
# This property controls the maximum size that the pool is allowed to reach, including both idle and in-use connections. Basically this value will determine the maximum number of actual connections to the database backend.
# Default: 10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=100
#This property controls the maximum number of milliseconds that a client (that's you) will wait for a connection from the pool. If this time is exceeded without a connection becoming available, a SQLException will be thrown.
#Lowest acceptable connection timeout is 250 ms. Default: 30000 (30 seconds)
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=600000
# This property controls the maximum amount of time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool. This setting only applies when minimumIdle is defined to be less than maximumPoolSize
# Default: 600000 (10 minutes)
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
# This property controls the maximum lifetime of a connection in the pool. An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed.
# Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000

## Jpa
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
# Disable feature detection by this undocumented parameter. Check the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServiceImpl.configure method for more details.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB

## Resources
spring.resources.add-mappings=false

# Allow OPTIION requests for authentication
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true

# Default port
server.port = 8080

# Debug mode
#logging.level.root = debug
```

Comment: Based in your pom file, I think that you are using H2 (in-memory DB) for your test and postgres for the real app; since you are trying to run the app you need to specify the url of your database in the properties file using the spring properties, for example: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://here_your_url:5432/here_your_db [...]
spring.datasource.username=here_your_username [...]
spring.datasource.password=here_your_password [...]

Comment: *the first time I'm playing with something like this* Please observe proper safety procedures at all time (PPE is no joke). It's all fun and games until the newbie meets [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 3):

if you are using springboot data jpa, use 'jdbcUrl' in your properties:

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database
```

if you are using springboot + mybatis, use 'url' in your properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database
```

Comment: spring.datasource.jdbcUrl does not exist in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html